# After migrating database from Access to SQL Server, it is not visible in when connecting to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, visual-studio-2010

I had a database in MS Access, I used a wizard (upsizing wizard) to migrate to SQL Server 2008 Express. When opening Management Studio, I can see and access the database:

[image]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJOp7.png)

But when I connect to the database in Visual Studio Servers -> Add connection wizard - I can only see the built-in databases `master`, `model`, `msdb`, `tempdb`. I don't see my database, which is called `VVDBSQL`

[image]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Abo3z.png)

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: probably try with `.\SQLEXPRESS`

Comment: Seems you've created your database on `(local)` - but in Visual Studio, you're looking at `machinename\SQLEXRPESS` .... it seems as if you have *at least **two** instances* of SQL Server running on your machine - and you're creating the database in one of them, but looking for it in the other.....